# OneSignal integration in iOS 8.0 Swift

Tags: ios, swift3, cocoapods, onesignal

I tried to integrate onesignal push library with my iOS app by followng their tutorial(https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup). However after adding OneSignal pod using cocoapods I'm getting following error

> /Pods/IQKeyboardManagerSwift/IQKeyboardManagerSwift/IQKeyboardManager.swift:514:35:
>   'shared' is unavailable: Use view controller based solutions where
>   appropriate instead.

IQKeyboardManagerSwift is another pod added using cocoapods.
I tried various solutions mentioned in Stackoverflow but nothing worked. Is there anyway to fix this issue permanently?

Comment: Try `pod deintegrate; pod clean; pod update`. Then delete DerivedData, clean your workspace and rebuild. Seems like you are using an older version of IQKeyboardManager also

Comment: @nathan I'm getting following error on the second command. [!] Unknown command: `clean`

Comment: Then try everything except clean (not sure if it was deleted some versions ago)

Comment: Still the issue is remaining

Answer (score 0):

Skip the 1st step (1. Add Notification Service Extension) in the tutorial. Then it will run without any issue.